# CLOSE_WAIT sockets with axis2 1.4.1

Tags: sockets, apache-axis

I am working on system J2EE app that uses AXIS2 1.4.1 to make web service calls over SSL 

 

I have the same issue as:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-2883

**CLOSE_WAIT slowly building up over the period of time. **


This forces us to restart the application in production every few days because open files build up on the jvm corresponding to the CLOSE_WAIT Sockets.

I see lots of posts over the web to upgrade AXIS to solve this issue but at this stage it’s almost impossible to upgrade AXIS since the application is in production and there are other dependencies to axis so we will need to end to end test the app – which is impossible..

 
 from AXIS 1.5.6:

 http://docs.huihoo.com/apache/axis/axis2-1.5.1/release-notes.html

```
Fix for the dreaded "CLOSE_WAIT" problem (JIRA issues 935, 2883, etc). 
We now share an instance of HTTPClient across each ConfigurationContext (i.e. each Axis2 server or ServiceClient) - connection reuse is now automatic. 
This means the REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT flag is no longer necessary or useful, nor is creating your own MultithreadedHttpConnectionManager.
```

Any way we can minimize the number of CLOSE_WAIT sockets on AXIS2 1.4.1?

 Thanks

Comment: If the problem is in Axis the solution is going to be in Axis as well. You're gong to have to change something and you're going to have to test it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This saved my life:

http://axis.8716.n7.nabble.com/Stubs-amp-Options-Configuration-td44576.html


Options o = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();

o.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);

o.setProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_ACCEPT_GZIP, Boolean.TRUE);

**o.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Boolean.TRUE);**

o.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, getHttpClient());